# How can I make an arrow function show up in the functions section of the Outline search instead of the variables section?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

The VS Code code navigation is not working with arrow functions defined:

```
async function all(req: Request, res: Response) {
.....

const checkLogin = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
```

When I display the code navigation, this is what I see:
[image]

I would like to have the `checkLogin` definition in the functions section. Is it possible?

Comment: arrow functions are anonymous functions, they have no name, how should they end up in the function list, if I assign the same arrow function to 20 variables do they all have to  be listed in the function part, and if I later assign an int/string to a variable should it be or not be listed

Comment: @rioV8 I think a case could be made for const variables: the variable itself has a name, and the value can't be reassigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`checkLogin` is a variable. It happens to be a `const` variable that references a `Function` object, but evidently, VS Code doesn't interpret that as a special case, so it displays it in the "variables" section of the part of the outline search, and not the "functions" section.

If you *really* wanted it in the "functions" section, you could rewrite it like so:

```
async function checkLogin (req: Request, res: Response) {
```